# What are the logistics in converting PSD to HTML, from the project managers standpoint?

Tags: website-design

I know this question so elementary, and I apologize in advance. Feel free to close it if it doesn't meet this sites criteria. I am managing my first web project, and am currently getting the PSDs designed. As soon as they are done, I am sending them for markup. To make things go faster, I am going to send them one page at a time (as soon as they are done being designed) to the front end developer. At this time, the sprites, mouseovers, popups, things of that sort won't be finished yet, as I am doing that at the very end with my designer. I planned on getting everything marked up, and then sending over these little details to the front end developer at the very end. Is this the normal process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before sending your PSD for markup I strongly suggest you to show your PSD to final customer and ask him for feedback.

Only when your customer agreed on a final graphic layout he likes, you can then send your PSD for markup.

I'm telling this because usually to the final customer we send the image (PSD to JPG) of the layout showing also how the menu buttons (and almost all the elements that changes on mouseover) look like when mouse is moved over them.

Comment: I AM the owner, thanks though :) So any feedback on my original question?